# Title of question can change when it appears in "Related" list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Here's an example.  This question had some revisions to its title:

[Comparison of two convergence conditions for sequences of non-negative numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839/if-sum-n1-infty-fraca-nn2-is-finite-does-frac1n2-sum-i1n)

https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1839/revisions

but when cited in the list of Related questions here

[If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}^{3}$ converges does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766/if-sum-n1-infty-a-n3-converges-does-sum-n1-infty-fraca-n)

it appears with the title from revision #2 (of 3).  It's currently the second-to-last one on the list.

Answer (score 3):

The question you mention now displays with the current title. Looks like the related questions database doesn't get updated every time a title is edited, but get synced up some time later.

Comment: We can infer, though, that the related questions data stores a reference not to the master link for a question (whatever appears in the overall math.SE "Questions" list, and which would resolve to the current latest version of each question) but to the latest edit of that question at a particular time.  Whether this is a bug or a design decision I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The related question list is periodically refreshed as questions are read, so this is normal.